# What is this $PATH in Linux and how to modify it

Tags: linux, path

I have a few questions on this $PATH in Linux.

I know it tells the shell which directories to search for executable files, so:

1. What does it mean an environmental variable?
2. How to change its path? and is it recommended to change it?
3. IF i change it what are the consequences?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get your path current `$PATH` variable type in:

```
echo $PATH
```

It tells your shell where to look for binaries.

Yes, you can change it - for example add to the `$PATH` folder with your custom scripts.

So: if your scripts are in `/usr/local/myscripts` to execute them you will have to type in a full path to the script: `/usr/local/myscripts/myscript.sh`
After changing your `$PATH` variable you can just type in `myscript.sh` to execute script.

Here is an example of `$PATH` from RHEL:

> /usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/home/user/bin

To change your `$PATH` you have to either edit `~/.profile` (or `~/.bash_profile`) for user or global `$PATH` setting in `/etc/profile`.

One of the consequences of having inaccurate `$PATH` variables is that shell will not be able to find and execute programs without a full `$PATH`.

Comment: Oh my God, you clarified it all for me by your statement --> "So: if your scripts are in /usr/local/myscripts to execute them you will have to type in a full path to the script: /usr/local/myscripts/myscript.sh After changing your $PATH variable you can just type in myscript.sh to execute script." Thanks a lot

Comment: and while you're at it can you also explain briefly what is this --> ~/.bashrc

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated just bash commands which are executed after you log in. Please look into man bash and search for bashrc.

Comment: in linux mint look in your home folder at .bashrc and .profile for path declarations

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, you are correct in your statement of what $PATH does.  If you were to break it somehow (as per your third point), you will have to manually type in /usr/bin/xyz if you want to run a program in /usr/bin from the terminal.  Depending on how individual programs work, this might break some programs that invoke other ones, as they will expect to just be able to run ls or something.

So if you were to play around with $PATH, I would suggest saving it somewhere first.  Use the command line instruction

```
echo $PATH > someRandomFile.txt
```

to save it in someRandomFile.txt

You can change $PATH using the export command.  So

```
export PATH=someNewPath
```

HOWEVER, this will completely replace $PATH with someNewPath.  Since items in path are separated by a ":", you can add items to it (best not to remove, see above) by executing

```
export PATH=$PATH:newPath
```

The fact that it is an environmental variable means that programs can find out its value, ie it is something that is set about the environment that the program is running in.  Other environmental variables include things like the current directory and the address of the current proxy.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple and i do like this way.

Open the linux bash shell and print the environment variables:

```
printenv
```

I copy "`PATH`" variable to a text editor and edit as I want. Then update the `PATH` like this

```
export PATH= /variable dir list/
```

It Works.

or if you want to add an single variable use this command.

```
export PATH = $PATH:/variable_dir_path/
```

This will extends the PATH with your new directory path.