# How to add shebang #! with php script on linux?

Tags: php, linux, shebang

I'm having a little issue with adding shebang #! with my php script on RedHat linux. I have a small piece of test code with shebang added (I've tried different variations as well), but I get the following error message everytime I try to run the script.

Error msg:

```
-bash: script.php: command not found
```

Test script:

```
#!/bin/env php    
<?php echo "test"; ?>
```

Shebang #! variations:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Comment: It's obvious - that's why he is asking :)

Comment: @JoelFan the PHP documentation seems to disagree with you: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php#example-375

Comment: @JoelFan - people have the freedom to express their silly thoughts on blogs, don't do it on a site where we help other developers. Thank you. To answer the question about the error - it's most likely because of CR\LF combination that comes after your first line. Use hex editor to check whether you have \n\r and if yes, remove carriage return. CHMOD +x yourfile.php to make it executable too.

Comment: offtopic, should be moved to shell usage

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It should (for most systems) be `#!/usr/bin/env php`, but your error isn't related to that.

> ```
> -bash: script.php: command not found
> ```

It says that **script.php** is not found.

If the problem was the shebang line then the error would say something like:

```
bash: script.php: /usr/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Presumably, you are typing `script.php` and the file is not in a directory on your `$PATH` or is not executable.

1. Make it executable: `chmod +x script.php`.
2. Type the path to it instead of just the filename, if it is in the current directory then: `./script.php`.

Instead of 2, you can move/copy/symlink the file to somewhere listed in `$PATH` or [modify the `$PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560332/what-is-this-path-in-linux-and-how-to-modify-it) to include the directory containing the script.

Comment: Also make sure you have Unix line endings in the script and not DOS.  DOS line endings will give you a similar error.

Answer (score 20):

If you script is not located in your `/usr/local/bin` and is executable, you have to prefix calling your script with `php` like this:

```
php myscrip.php
```

For shebangs, here is what I use:

Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

or this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env php` is much preferred, as it lets the system say where the executable is installed

Answer (score 5):

In reply to @NVRM's comment regarding only single use of `-d`, this is not true.

Start with a `chmod +x script` as

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and run `script | grep -E 'memory_limit|error_reporting'`, and you'll see

```
error_reporting => no value => no value
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
```

Now add some `-d` entries so you have

```sh
#!/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=2G -d error_reporting=-1
<?php
phpinfo();
```

and re-run `script | grep -E 'memory_limit|error_reporting'`, and you'll now see

```
error_reporting => -1 => -1
memory_limit => 2G => 2G
```

Thus demonstrating you can set multiple options.

In fact, the entire command line is what you are working with here. So you can load extensions, use a different config, etc., everything you can do at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

find callable shebang for PHP in Linux,
Don't memorize this it, learn how to use it

```
which php
```

output

```
zeus@pop-os:~$ which php
/usr/bin/php
```

then shebang must be

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving here some little notes:

---

**To use a php binary located inside the same folder.**

As example a php7.2 executable copied from `/usr/bin` is in the same path along a `hello` script.

```
#!./php7.2
<?php

echo "Hello!";
```

To run it:

```
./hello
```

Which behave just as equal as:

```
./php7.2 hello
```

This give portability, but beware of system architectures, the php binary might not match the target platform.

---

**Setting allowed memory from the hashbang:**

We can set **one INI entry** from the hashbang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -d memory_limit=2048M
<?php
phpinfo();
exit;
```

Then to see if php had understood, using phpinfo():

```
./myphpProg | grep memory
```

Correct shell output should contain:

```
memory_limit => 2048M => 2048M
```

Doing the above is similar as this command line:

```
php -d memory_limit=2048M myphpProg.**php**
```

This is why we can set only one ini value in hashbangs, as php accept only one **-d** parameter at a time.

Comment: Multiple options are allowed. Please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552213/2161941